# I can't understand what a piece of code while doing a course in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
sum_of_dice = die.sample(2, replace=True).sum().loc[0]
```

This is the code to find the sum of the faces of two die thrown together. In this code I didn't understand what `loc[0]` is doing

The code is working. But I'd like to know what the `.loc[0]` is doing in this code:

```
import pandas as pd
die = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sum_of_dice = die.sample(2, replace=True).sum().loc[0]
print('Sum of dice is', sum_of_dice)
```

Comment: did you read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `die` is defined as a `pandas.DataFrame` it is inherently 2-dimensional.

```
die = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
die

   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

**`pandas.DataFrame.sample`** will return another `pandas.DataFrame` that is 2-dimensional

```
roll = die.sample(2, replace=True)
roll

   0
1  2
4  5
```

When we `pandas.DataFrame.sum`, by default, we sum over each column and return a `pandas.Series` where the index of that `pandas.Series` is the columns object of the `pandas.DataFrame` we summed.

```
roll.sum()

0    7
dtype: int64
```

This is a `pandas.Series` with one value.  If we want just the first value, we can use `loc[0]`

```
roll.sum().loc[0]

7
```

---

#### What I would do

Use a `pandas.Series` to define `die`

```
import pandas as pd
die = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sum_of_dice = die.sample(2, replace=True).sum()
print('Sum of dice is', sum_of_dice)
```

In this case `die` is a 1-dimensional `pandas.Series` and thus, so is the `die.sample(2, replace=True)`.  Consequently, and forturnately, the sum of a `pandas.Series` is a scalar... and what we want.  No need to use `loc`.  Also, creating a `pandas.DataFrame` takes a marginal amount more effort than creating a `pandas.Series`.  In addition, calling `loc` has a smidgen of overhead as well.  All together, we save the creation of 2 `pandas.DataFrames` (One from `pd.Series` instead of `pd.DataFrame` and Two from `die.sample` which creates another `pandas.Series` instead of another `pandas.DataFrame`) and we spare ourselves a `loc` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick overview on how Pandas loc attribute works https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/

Answer (score 0):

Loc seems to be some sort of list. Meaning it stores (or can store) multiple values.
The code only wants to access the value at index 0 (which is the starting index).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas loc indexer can be used with DataFrames for two different use cases:

a) Selecting rows by label/index

b) Selecting rows with a boolean/conditional lookup

For more, please go through:

https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/#loc-selection